# SDK for Android:How facebook check the Hash key?

Tags: android, facebook, security, facebook-android-sdk

When we want to use Facebook SDK for Android as our SSO solution, we need to put our Android application signature into our Facebook application settings (Step 5 of [Facebook sdk for android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/#sig)).

And that signature should be generated by  running the keytool that comes with the Android SDK.

I am curious how facebook verify this signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For facebook app to function we need to provide Facebook "App Id"
- For android platform we need to provide package name, class name & "HashKey
- App will mostly have 2 HashKey for "Debug" & "Release" version of app
- When app access facebook, SDK internally generate & compare the HashKey with one submitted during the facebook app

Answer (score 2):

After more than one year, I think I'd better answer my question.

Android's app can get other app's signature by:

```
public String WriteSignature(String packageName)
{     
   PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
   String sig = ""; 
   PackageInfo pi = null;
   try {
       pi = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }

   try {
       for (Signature signature : pi.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           sig = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
           Log.d(ACTIVITY_TAG, sig);
       }
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return sig;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this code gets us the hash we provide to facebook. however did you manage to find an authentic documentation source where this is mentioned. I am also curious to know how this is managed. How the App id, package, and hash keys are linked at Google and FB servers when application makes a call.